# Is it safe to use references in Qt signals and slots?

Tags: c++, qt, pass-by-reference, signals-slots, qt-signals

I am working with Qt for some time, and I still wasn't able to understand properly if it is safe to use references in signals and slots.

In my understanding, it is unsafe, because if a connection is not direct (signal in one thread, slot in another) — then this reference will be "remembered" in some intermediate object, and it will become dangling. However, if a connection is direct, it should be pretty safe.

There are no warnings in Qt Creator when I am using references, and also, it seems to work even when I tried to artificially create a situation where the passed object is dead before the slot is called. It seemed to work fine. Maybe it is because Qt somehow handles my references internally and still copies this object?

So, my question is: is it safe? Even if it is safe, should I do it? Are there any "best practices" for it?

Comment: As long as the life-time of the object you reference haven't ended when you use it, it should work fine.

Comment: In C++ it is programmer who is responsible for ensuring memory safety, so there is no such thing as "safe references".

Comment: If you pass a dead reference, that's always UB. Anything can happen, including what you observed happening. It's not very useful to try to reason about UB. For example, an area of memory may contain old data, or be partially overwritten, or contain non-crashing values by random chance. It may behave differently every time you run the program. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following blog post contains an extended answer and explanation https://embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/.

TLDR. Qt connections can either be `Direct` (default when signal and slot are emitted/received in the same thread) or `Queued` (default when signal is emitted in one thread and the slot receives it in another). In a `Direct` connection Qt behaves as expected with the usual C++ semantics (i.e. pass-by-value gets copied, references do not). In a `Queued` one a copy is always made no matter what the (const)refness of the actual type provided is.

To answer your question, it seems that the reference going out of scope in which the connection is `Direct` would lead to UB. Note that depending on your example this would not necessarily always lead to a crash - it could well be that the reference is dangling but the memory it points to is still valid.

As for the best practices, the blog post suggests always using const ref in both the signal and the slot as that minimizes copies. Since it's ~10 years old however, I'd be keen to repeat the experiment described in it before completely trusting the results. I'd do it myself but I don't have Qt installed anywhere currently - might come back at a later date and post a comment with the results.

More about Qt connection types and their behaviour can be found here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. It is exactly what I was looking for. And I was hoping that Qt did this under the hood but wasn't sure. Well, now I am.